# How to check for incoming SCP connections on Linux?

Tags: linux, scp

I want to view if any SCP connections are coming to my Linux machine. 
How can I view those?

Comment: Is it sufficient to view any incoming ssh connection, or do you need to distinguish scp from other types of ssh connections?  Do you want to view current connections or view a log of past connections?

Comment: I just want to check the current/ongoing SSH & SCP connections.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can check the incoming connections by using below command.

```
ps aux | grep scp
```

You can also check the IP by using below command. scp use ssh to transfer files.

```
netstat -plant | grep sshd
```

Comment: `ps aux` wont help much for incoming connections. The second command is helpful tho.

Answer (score 3):

scp is using the ssh protocol, so any scp will also be logged in /var/log/secure as an ssh connection.

```
sudo grep sshd /var/log/secure |tail
```

or

```
journalctl /usr/sbin/sshd |tail
```

However, you will not distinguish this connection from a SSH session on the same account.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tcpdump -lnXvv dst port 22`. 
as root user.

Following is a sample output:

```
15:52:01.257950 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 7254, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 656)
172.17.27.130.52032 > 172.17.17.28.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9d77 (correct), seq 35152848:35153464, ack 16709, win 256, length 616
0x0000:  4500 0290 1c56 4000 7f06 5851 ac11 1b82  E....V@...XQ....
0x0010:  ac11 111c cb40 0016 4215 fe37 405f 5a61  .....@..B..7@_Za
0x0020:  5018 0100 9d77 0000 9a09 7a29 36ac 5c94  P....w....z)6.\.
0x0030:  dee2 8679 e3b6 aef3 9096 aa53 1ea4 87c3  ...y.......S....
0x0040:  308b b034 b53d 14af 096e 20ad c2ff 81bc  0..4.=...n......
0x0050:  3ede 8035 1ad4 5d3f 9a19 9d60 a7a3 60ad  >..5..]?...`..`.
```

This shows that a machine with IP 172.17.27.130 is sending data to 172.17.17.28.22 out of which 172.17.17.28 is dst host ip at port 22, which is for scp.